# Oracle SQL Compiles, but seems to break out of loop when select loop returns nothing/empty

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am still quite new to pl/sql... but here I have a script that works well when data exists...But I also need it to work when the select statement does NOT have any value to return (is empty). When the select statement is empty, dbms_output.put_line does not show anything, even when I write a complete string there, so I think the loop is exiting when nothing is found. Online, I stumbled upon Union and Exception...but nothing that seems to work accurately in a loop. 
**WHAT I AM ASKING IS:** How to run this script even when data DOES NOT EXIST??? AND How do I tell which value is empty? Is it the postal_code or the fipcode, or BOTH?

```
DECLARE 
    F33_35      VARCHAR2(3)     := rpad('0',3,'0');
BEGIN

FOR tabVals IN (SELECT DISTINCT pa.postal_code, fip.fipcode 
  FROM voucher v
  INNER JOIN cc_authorization cca
    ON cca.cc_authorization_id = v.cc_authorization_id
  INNER JOIN episode e
    ON cca.subsidy_id = e.episode_id
  INNER JOIN case c
    ON c.case_id = e.case_id
  INNER JOIN invoice_item ii
    ON ii.voucher_id = v.voucher_id
  INNER JOIN invoice i
    ON i.invoice_id = ii.invoice_id
  INNER JOIN svcperiod_info s
    ON s.svcperiod_id = i.svcperiod_id
 INNER JOIN party_contact_mech pcm
    ON pcm.party_id = c.identifying_party
  INNER JOIN postal_address pa
    ON pcm.contact_mech_id = pa.contact_mech_id
  INNER JOIN VT_FIPS_MAP fip
    ON substr(pa.POSTAL_CODE,1,5) = substr(fip.ZIPCODE,1,5)

  WHERE ii.status               = 8                     AND
        ii.net_amount           > 0                     AND
        s.end_dt                >= DATE'2017-04-01'     AND
        s.end_dt                <  DATE'2017-04-30'     AND 
        c.case_id               =  104570               AND
        pcm.contact_mech_purpose_cd = 4                 AND
        pcm.current_ind         = 1                     
  ORDER BY POSTAL_CODE, FIPCODE)
  LOOP
    F33_35 := substr(F33_35 || tabVals.fipcode,-3);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('F String: 50' || F33_35);                                         

    --- RESET certain variables for loop
    F33_35      := rpad('0',3,'0');

  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Define a variable `data_exists boolean default false;` then inside the loop set it to true.  After the loop: `if not data_exists then dbms_output.put_line('whatever you want to say'); end if;`

Comment: The loop is executed as many times as the query returns rows - so if that is zero...

Comment: Thanks @TonyAndrews. Specifically, I need to determine which specific value is empty...for example, is my postal_code empty, or my fipcode? Or is it not returning anything because BOTH are empty?

Comment: You can't determine from running a query what rows it is **not** returning!  You would need to write a different query for that - maybe using an outer join?

Comment: @TonyAndrews ooooo, that stinks! Ok, well thanks for the input!!!

Answer (score 0):

you are correct when you say

> ...I think the loop is exiting when nothing is found...

the cursor for loop can be considered a special case of regular loop.
eg.

```
for a in (<select statement>) LOOP
    --do stuff here
END LOOP;
```

is effectively just shorthand for

```
declare
  cursor c is
  <select statement>;

  a c%ROWTYPE;
begin

  open c;
  LOOP
    FETCH c INTO a;
    EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
    --do stuff here
  END LOOP;
```

so you can no see that no code would be executed if the query returns 0 rows.

possible the best solution for running code if your statement returns 0 rows is to set a flag inside the loop and check it afterwards. (as suggested by @tony-Andrews )

a second option is to rewrite as the long version of the loop above and move the `EXIT WHEN` statement to after the "do stuff"